# PowerShell Script to Detect duplicate hostnames - but only part of the hostname

Tags: powershell

If I have a list (csv, txt, array etc) of hostnames such as:

```
abc123A
aab123B
bcd123C
def123A
abb123B
abb123A
abb123B
```

How can I make sure the first 3 letters (site code) have only 1 instance/host in the array or list? I don't need any of the other hosts at a site, just one host from each unique site to represent my final list

```
$A = $(foreach ($line in Get-Content C:\Test1\File1.txt) {$line.tolower().split(" ")}) | sort | Get-Unique
$A.count
```

The above code only looks for duplicates essentially - could I specify the first 3 letters somehow to be looked at?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Group-Object` is your friend for things like this, which you could sort by count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
@("abc123A",
"aab123B",
"bcd123C",
"def123A",
"abb123B",
"abb123A",
"abb123B") | select @{ Name = 'Site';  Expression = {$_.SubString(0,3)}} | Select-Object -Property Site -Unique
```

This will produce the following:

```
Site                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
abc                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
aab                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
bcd                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
def                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
abb
```

It uses a calculated property to select the first three letters from the list.

If you want to see the groupings you can use this:

```
select @{ Name = 'Site';  Expression = {$_.SubString(0,3)}}, @{ Name = 'Host';  Expression = {$_}} | Group-Object -Property Site
```

Which will produce this:

```
Count Name                      Group                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
----- ----                      -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    1 abc                       {@{Site=abc; Host=abc123A}}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    1 aab                       {@{Site=aab; Host=aab123B}}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    1 bcd                       {@{Site=bcd; Host=bcd123C}}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    1 def                       {@{Site=def; Host=def123A}}                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    3 abb                       {@{Site=abb; Host=abb123B}, @{Site=abb; Host=abb123A}, @{Site=abb; Host=abb123B}}
```

If you only want one 'Host' from each 'Site', then Select the first from each group like this:

```
select @{ Name = 'Site';  Expression = {$_.SubString(0,3)}}, @{ Name = 'Host';  Expression = {$_}} | Group-Object -Property Site | %{$_.Group[0].Host}
```

Which will give you this:

```
abc123A
aab123B
bcd123C
def123A
abb123B
```

Comment: Thanks David, that is very close, i need the list of output as above but with the original end part of the hostname still present, how would that be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

You can find duplicates like this:

```
Get-Content .\names.txt |
    Group-Object @{e={$_.Substring(0,3)}} |
        Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

Which gives the following for your example:

```
Count Name Group                      
----- ---- -----                      
    3 abb  {abb123B, abb123A, abb123B}
    1 abc  {abc123A}                  
    1 aab  {aab123B}                  
    1 bcd  {bcd123C}                  
    1 def  {def123A}
```

If you want an array with only one item, say the first, from each group, then change it to:

```
$finalList = Get-Content .\names.txt |
                Group-Object @{e={$_.Substring(0,3)}} |
                    Sort-Object Count -Descending |
                        ForEach-Object {
                            $_.Group[0]
                        }
```

`$finalList` in this case will be:

```
abb123B
abc123A
aab123B
bcd123C
def123A
```

Comment: Nice one +1, struggling with the terminal on MacOs with pwsh I missed the point. Does the sort make sense if the dublettes are ignored anyway?

Comment: @LotPings, I added the sort in the first example just because it makes the output a bit clearer, and just left it in for the modified version.  You're right that it could be removed with no loss of functionality (unless the order _is_ important, but that wasn't mentioned).  For this small set, I don't think it matters, but I guess if you had a huge list of names, unnecessary sorting would be a bad idea.

Comment: Amazing, that's totally it, an array with one item from each unique site was what i required. Thank you for your help - Genius

Answer (score 1):

```
PS C:\> $HostNames | Group {$_.SubString(0, 3)}

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    1 abc                       {abc123A}
    1 aab                       {aab123B}
    1 bcd                       {bcd123C}
    1 def                       {def123A}
    3 abb                       {abb123B, abb123A, abb123B}
```

Or if you just would like the `Name` property:

```
PS C:\> $HostNames | Group {$_.SubString(0, 3)} | Select -Expand Name
abc
aab
bcd
def
abb
```

Answer (score 0):

Group the files with a calculated property with substring(0,3),
filter for groups with a count greater than 1 and
output the group joined to a string.

```
$Host |Group-Object {$_.Name.Substring(0,3)}| 
    Where-Object Count -gt 1| ForEach{
        "Prefix:{0} = {1}" -f $_.Name,($_.Group -join ',')
}
```

Sample output in folder with two files starting with `tmux`

```
Prefix:tmu = tmux-client-5328.log,tmux-server-5330.log
```

---

```
$Hostnames = @"
abc123A
aab123B
bcd123C
def123A
abb123B
abb123A
abb123B
"@

$Hostnames -split '\r?\n' |Group-Object {$_.Substring(0,3)} | 
    Where-Object Count -gt 1| ForEach-Object {
      "Dublettes:{0} = {1}" -f $_.Name,($_.Group -join ',')}
```

---

```
Dublettes:abb = abb123B,abb123A,abb123B
```